Yukawa Interaction with Chiral Fermions
I understand that an interaction like
$$g\overline\psi_L\psi_R\phi$$
is allowed in the SM (for the sake of this discussion lets ignore gauge charges and focus only on Lorentz invariance).
I want to build a Feynman diagram that has a mass vertex, so I can write an effective coupling, $$g'\overline\psi_L\psi_L\phi$$
However, dealing with the mass vertex has been a pain.
The way I would like to solve this is by use of appropriate projection operators. As I understand this would change the Lagrangian term to something like,
$$ h (P_L\psi)^\dagger \gamma^0 P_R\psi\phi $$
$$ P_L = \frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5) , P_R = \frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)$$
The issue arises when I try to calculate this vertex on a Feynman diagram, since it seems like the vertex factor would be $$ ihP_LP_R $$ which is 0 since, $$ P_LP_R = 0 $$.
One way to solve this is by redefining h to have a gamma matrix in it, and then using a vertex factor like $$ P_L h'\gamma^\nu P_R $$ which seems to solve the problem, but also seems to change the scalar nature of $$ \phi $$?
How do I resolve these two things? What is the appropriate vertex factor?
Said another way;
How do you properly include left and right handed projection operators into a Yukawa-type vertex?

your proposed vertex is not Lorentz invariant, it is not a valid interaction.

@AccidentalFourierTransform You mean the effective coupling? Yes, I dont care about its invariance right now. But if you are referring to something else, being more clear is more helpful!
If something isn't Lorentz invariant, could you point out why, and what you might do to fix it?

$\psi_L^\dagger\psi_L$ is not a Lorentz scalar. It is not a valid term in a Lagrangian.

Yes, that is not a term in my Lagrangian. This is an effective coupling I would like to probe. I can do this via a mass vertex. I have an incoming LH particle, that has a mass vertex which changes to RH, interacts with scalar, and leaves as LH.
This is the process I need to compute.

You are connecting a mass vertex to a Yukawa vertex with a fermion propagator. To leading order in m/p, you get the term in my answer.

I suspect you are trapped in bad notation, which, sadly, is quite common, even though you appreciate the crucial chirality-flipping $\gamma^0$ involved in the overbar.
The more sensible/tasteful representation of your terms, utilized by the better authors, is
$$g\overline{\psi_L}\psi_R\phi=g\overline{\psi}P_R\psi_R\phi=  g\overline{\psi} \psi_R\phi,$$
just like a mass term, which it produces in the SM,
$$
m ~\overline{\psi_L}\psi_R.
$$
One hermitianizes terms in the action in the end.

I want to build a Feynman diagram that has a mass vertex, so I can write an effective coupling, $g'\overline{\psi_L}\psi_L\phi$

As the commenters pointed out,  your term, if this is what you wrote, is automatically zero, and mercifully does not produce Lorentz-invariant mass terms; I'm not sure why you connect it to a mass vertex. A mass vertex is what is written above!
My first guess for your two-chirality-flip effective interaction, so, then no chirality-flip interaction, is
$$igm\phi\overline{\psi_L}(/\!\!\partial ~/\Box) ~~\psi_L= igm \phi~~\overline{\psi}(/\!\!\partial ~/\Box)  \psi_L,$$
which doesn't vanish. It only vanishes for infinite momenta, since the chirality-flipping mass is suppressed. This term flips LH to RH, and then, to LH again, in the same breath, so to speak.

I have some gauge singlet fermion fields. LH and RH chiralities.
They share some mass term in the Lagrangian (This term is Lorentz invariant)
There is also a chargeless scalar field, $\phi$
Thus, one can DIRECTLY couple LH and RH chiral fields to this scalar (Lorentz invariant)
Using these two interaction terms, we can INDIRECTLY couple LH fields to scalar, by use of a mass term;
LH -> mass -> RH -> scalar -> LH
I want to express this as an effective coupling strength. This is the computation I want to do. My best guess is -igP_R

..so you want your original LH to chirality flip by the mass in the propagator and then chirality flip through the Yukawa? The propagator will insert a $\gamma^\mu $ in the effective vertex...

yes! Could you elaborate more on this gamma factor insertion? This is the key part I dont understand

I updated my answer. You connect the mass vertex which flips chirality to RH, propagate the RH freely through the  p-slash to a RH, and then emit a scalar flipping chirality again, to a LH. To chirality flips amount to none such, so LH to LH...

There are some issues with this answer. For one, while a mass vertex is allowed, one must sum up contributions from all mass insertions. The resulting effective coupling has no momentum dependence.
Instead, one can consider a new field, \psi = \psi_L + \psi_R and add a projection operator to select the desired chirality.
At face value this seems correct, but Ive been told its not so easy. The proper gamma insertions depend on if particles are Majorana or Dirac, and if the scalar is real or complex. This is part I do not understand.

You cannot have spinors simultaneously Majorana and Weyl in 4-dim. The scalar may be real or complex, as in the SM. p is a FT shorthand for $\partial$, so $/!!\partial ~/\Box$ in your effective term! Should all have been part of your SMEFT course, but you surely do not wish to wag a review on such through this tail...

As for all mass insertions, you do that,  but there is only one for your chiral coupling. The scalar coupling must eat a LH to yield a bar-LH, so the mass insertion is on the right. Consult your SMEFT notes!

I'm so sick of hearing this 'just check your notes'. If it were that simple, I wouldn't have had to make an account just to ask this question. In none of the textbooks or notes I have do they talk about yukawa interactions between chiral fermions, or majorana fermions in this detail. Moreover, many mass insertions work, for example, LH->mass->RH->mass->LH->mass->RH also works, as well as an infinite number of extensions. Summing these together gives just a standard propagator with mass equal to these mass insertions (assuming theyre all the same)

The better solution, I am confident in saying, is to consider a 4 component fermion, with LH and RH chiral components interacting with a scalar and emitting another 4 component fermion. This is very natural too, as one can just take the original coupling and replace chiral fields with 4-component fields and projection operators. But, aparently, this process also depends on the majorana nature of these fermions, as well as the complex nature of the scalar. This I have been told by a trustworthy source. However, I am having a hard time understanding this detail

I'm sorry, I can't shadow-box with transmitted statements of the sort. Badger your source to get to the bottom of it. Both your framing and setup are extraordinarily opaque and off-mainstream, which might explain why I am the only one engaging in this....
